# How to convert QueryPerformanceCounter to Unix nanoseconds (epoch)

Tags: windows, unix, timer, epoch

I am using `QueryPerformanceCounter` windows syscall in order to get high-precision timestamp.

I need to convert it to unix epoch (in nanoseconds) as I am going to pass the value to an API that needs it in this format

Could anybody help me understanding how to accomplish this?

Comment: But you're measuring time differences with `QueryPerformanceCounter` it is not intended as timestamp, so it seems not to be the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QueryPerformanceCounter` does not return a timestamp with a fixed offset to the current time (as in UTC, or, the time shown by a wall clock), so you cannot convert it to UNIX time.

However, time differences measured using `QueryPerformanceCounter` can be converted to nanoseconds (or any time unit) by dividing by the result of `QueryPerformanceFrequency` (to get seconds) and multiplying by, e.g., `10^9` to get nanoseconds.

Answer (score 1):

As per comments above, `QueryPerformanceCounter` is not the right way to go.

I have found `GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime` that suits my needs